# AngularJS controller not properly loaded during ng-Route otherwise()

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm learning an example of a single page application using angularjs. Here's the relevant code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        // configure the routes
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        // route for the home page
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/about/', {
        // route for the about page
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/contact/', {
        // route for the contact page
        templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
        // when all else fails
        templateUrl: 'pages/routeNotFound.html',
        controller: 'notFoundController'
        });
        });
        app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Welcome to my home page!';
        });
        app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Find out more about me.';
        });
        app.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Contact us!';
        });
        app.controller('notFoundController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted';
            $scope.attemptedPath = $location.path();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeController">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Website</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#!contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

routeNotFound.html

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>This is not good</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <p class="has-error">{{attemptedPath}}</p>
</div>
```

When I click on Home or About or Contact the page renders correctly. But if I visit any other URL, routeNotFound.html is injected correctly to div[ng-view] but the data is not bound. I get:

```
This is not good
{{message}}

{{attemptedPath}}
```

It seems notFoundController is not correctly made available to the view when .otherwise() is called inside route. $scope.message and $scope.attemptedPath is not bound to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing $`locationService` injection in your  **notFoundController**

```
app.controller('notFoundController', function ($scope,$location /*<--- location injected here*/) {
            $scope.message = 'There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted';
            $scope.attemptedPath = $location.path();
        });
```

Here is a full sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  // configure the routes
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
  // route for the home page
  template: '<h1>My page home</h1><br />{{message}}',
  controller: 'homeController'
  })
  .when('/about/', {
  // route for the about page
  template: '<h1>My page about</h1><br />{{message}}',
  controller: 'aboutController'
  })
  .when('/contact/', {
  // route for the contact page
  template: '<h1>My page contact</h1><br />{{message}}',
  controller: 'contactController'
  })
  .otherwise({
  // when all else fails
 template: '<h1>Not found page</h1><br />{{message}}',
  controller: 'notFoundController'
  });
  });
  app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = 'Welcome to my home page!';
  });
  app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = 'Find out more about me.';
  });
  app.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.message = 'Contact us!';
  });
  app.controller('notFoundController', function ($scope,$location) {
   $scope.message = 'There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted';
   $scope.attemptedPath = $location.path();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script>
  
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeController">
 <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Website</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#!about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#!contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#!notsdflj"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Not found</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <div id="main">
  <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```